# combineReducers() not working in React Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

This is my Code for Store

```
import { combineReducers, createStore } from "redux";
 
import counterReducer from "./../Counter/counter.reducer";
const rootReducer = combineReducers({ first: counterReducer });
 
const store = createStore(rootReducer);

export default store;
```

and the Component :

```
const Sid = () => {
  const num = useSelector((state) => state.counter);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Count value is {num}</h1>
      
      <button onClick={() => dispatch(increaseCounter())}>Add 5 </button>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch(decreaseCounter())}>Subtract 50</button>
    </div>
   
  );
};
```

**Output:**

[image: output]

Code Works Fine If I don't use combine reducer and directly use single reducer in the `createStore() function`

Please help me to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4):

When you use `combineRreducers`, your store object will have the same keys as the object you pass in with the reducer return value as the value.

So in your case the store should look like this

```
{
  first: {
    counter: 0
  }
}
```

the problem is that you try to read the value from `state.counter` in your selector instead of `state.first.counter`

Simply change your selector to

```js
const num = useSelector(state => state.first.counter);
```

Answer (score 1):

Below are a few refined answers for this issue:

**Approach one:** If you use the **connect** method to map your state to props and pros to dispatch, you must add the key name while accessing the state value.

**Approach two:** The same is applicable if you are using **useSelector hook** also.

Code below:

The required change if you use Approach 1 for the above question

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
return {
    counter: state.first.counter,
  };
}
```

The required change is you use approach 2 for the above question

```
const num = useSelector((state) => state.first.counter);
```

Answer (score 0):

A piece of advice.
**Always write every line of code with a purpose.**

According to the [official documentation](https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers), `combineReducers` use for below mentioned scenarios.

> As your app grows more complex, you'll want to split your reducing function into separate functions, each managing independent parts of the state.

You have only one reducer. Then don't need to combine reducers. Just pass your reducer simply as mentioned below.

```js
import { createStore } from "redux";
import counterReducer from "./../Counter/counter.reducer";

const store = createStore(counterReducer); // Just pass `counterReducer` directly

export default store;
```

Let me know if you need further support.

Comment: Sir, I actually know that we should use what we need I was actually having 5 five reducers but the code was not working and then I tried again with a single reducer but still, It was not working so then I decided to ask this question on StackOverflow. Thank you for your help  It means a lot!

Comment: ah okay. Then you have to do just as @Asaf Aviv says in the above.